# ubuntu can't support a higher resolution that my laptop can support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, gnome, resolution

I have a HP laptop which can support 1600x900. But after I install ubuntu 9.10 on it, it can only support up to 1280x700. My laptop has a Nvidia graphics card. And i am using GNOME as my desktop environment.

Can you please tell me how can I configure ubuntu 9.10 to have 1600x900?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you have the latest nVidia driver installed and properly configured.

If that doesn't work, you can hack your xorg.conf to force the higher resolution (but be aware that if the drivers you have installed don't support the resolution, you will be forced to fix your xorg.conf via the console):

[Need to force resolution in xorg.conf - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=129379#post129379)

Comment: I went to http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index5.aspx?lang=en-us. But I am not sure which one to use.  My graphic card is '1GB Nvidia GeForce GT 320M'. But that site does not have one which matches it.